# Swift delegate beetween two VC without segue

Tags: swift, delegates, pass-data

I have 3 classes:

- ChatLogControoller
- GetImageFromLibraty(NSObject class)
- ImagePreviewViewController

I want to press a clip from the first VC, then open the media library to pick an image. Then the selected image is passed to the third VC as a previewController. Then if I select 'done' I want to pass it to the first VC.

**1st VC**

```
class ChatLogControoller: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, DataSentDelegate {

func recievePhoto(data: UIImage) {
    imageFromView = data
    print("-------\(imageFromView = data)")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let vc = ImagePreviewController()
    self.vc.delegate = self
}
```

2nd class its just picker of image, so i pass image to 3rd VC and this image appears on imageView of 3rd VC successfully!

**my 3rd VC**

```
protocol DataSentDelegate {
    func recievePhoto(data: UIImage)
}
class PreviewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var delegate : DataSentDelegate? = nil

var aImageView: UIImageView!
var aImage: UIImage!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionSend))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(actionBack))

}

@objc func actionBack() {

    dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
}

@objc func actionSend() {

    let data = aImageView.image
    delegate?.recievePhoto(data: data!)
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing?

Comment: @V_rohit what i miss in code to pass data from 3rd VC to 1st VC?

Comment: call the delegate method in 2 VC from which you are passing the photo to 3rd VC

Comment: @V_rohit but how i can pass it from 3rd VC to 1st vc in this situation?

Comment: you created the protocol in your 3rd VC just call this protocol in your 1st VC by using protocol you can pass the data to the 1st VC

Comment: @V_rohit i provide sample of my code... is it correct? Because recievePhoto if 1st VC is empty

Comment: you just want to pass an image from 3rd VC to 1st VC

Comment: @V_rohit exactly...

Comment: I am not sure it looks correct...I think the missing part is calling delegate at right... I need to do it by myself first... just wait for few moments let me do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174795/discussion-between-george-heints-and-v-rohit).

Comment: Hey... I got your solution.... sorry for reply very very late.. I am giving the answer hope it will help you... I will explain that later just use that and you will get your solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create one more protocol in your `SecondViewController` to Pass that delegate from `ThirdViewController` to `FirstViewController`.

**FirstViewController**:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, DataSentDelegate, dataSentDelegate  {

    @IBOutlet weak var imagefromThirdVC: UIImageView!

    var thirdVCImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) { 
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController2") as! ViewController2
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func goToThirdVC() {
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController3") as! ViewController3
        vc.delegate = self
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

    func recievePhoto(data: UIImage) {
        thirdVCImage = data
        imagefromThirdVC.image = thirdVCImage
    }
}
```

**SecondViewController**:

```
import UIKit

protocol dataSentDelegate {
    func goToThirdVC()
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var passingImage: UIImageView!

    var delegate: dataSentDelegate? = nil

    var images: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        images = UIImage(named: "screen")
    }

    @IBAction func actionButton(_ sender: Any) {
        self.delegate?.goToThirdVC()
    }

}
```

**ThirdViewController**:

```
import UIKit

protocol DataSentDelegate {
    func recievePhoto(data: UIImage)
}

class ViewController3: UIViewController {

    var delegate: DataSentDelegate? = nil

    @IBOutlet weak var passedImageView: UIImageView!

    var passedImage: UIImage!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        passedImage = UIImage(named: "screen")
        passedImageView.image = passedImage
    }

    @IBAction func action(_ sender: Any) {

        let data = passedImageView.image
        delegate?.recievePhoto(data: data!)
        //   delegate?.goToFirstVC()

        guard let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers else {
            return
        }

        for firstViewController in viewControllers {
            if firstViewController is ViewController {
                self.navigationController?.popToViewController(firstViewController, animated: true)
                break
            }
        }

    }

}
```

[image]