# iOS/ swift : moving between view controllers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

suppose I have a MainTabBarController, from one of it's tabs, I go to FirstViewController, then from FirstViewController, I go to SecondViewController (all with present modally), in SecondViewController when user hits cancel button, I want to go back to MainTabBarController, without showing FirstViewController, can I do this without NavigationController? cus I have no NavigationController in current version of my code and it will cost me many changes :(

Comment: yes you can do this :D

Comment: do you know how?

Comment: yes you can use protocol and delegate method to achieve this

Comment: this way it shows SecondViewController disappear, then FirstViewController disappear and this is what I don't want to happen!

Comment: it will directly take you to your mainViewController

Comment: I should dismiss my First and Second ViewController, right? or you suggest don't dismissing them and just go to MainTabBar?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281372/swift-delegate-beetween-two-vc-without-segue/51287027#51287027 take help of this answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your `SecondViewController` you can call below code on tap of cancel button, which gets the `presentingViewController` of `SecondViewController` -> `presentingViewController` of `FirstViewController` which is a `TabBarController` and call `dismiss` on it.

```
@objc func dismiss(_ button: UIButton) {
    self.presentingViewController?.presentingViewController?.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```